# create matrix from raw data

Tags: r, matrix

My data looks like this:

```
> head(data, 20)
# A tibble: 20 x 2
   hosp   zip  
   <chr>  <chr>
 1 010001 14843
 2 010001 36303
 3 010016 13320
 4 010021 10468
 5 010023 36040
 6 010023 36116
 7 010023 36116
 8 010023 36116
 9 010024 36401
10 010029 10025
11 010029 11412
12 010029 11733
13 010033 14086
14 010033 14701
15 010033 35244
16 010034 12308
17 010038 11413
18 010039 10011
19 010039 11704
20 010039 35749
```

`hosp`is hospital id and `zip` is zip code. Patients in each hospital came from multiple zip codes. How can I create a matrix to present for each hospital, how many patients were from each zip code?
Ideal matrix would be like this:

```
zip     010001  010016   010021   ... hosp
14843   1       0        0        
36303   1       0        0
13320   0       1        0
10468   0       0        1
```

Thanks!!

Comment: What about `table(data)`?

Comment: `as.matrix(table(data))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As was stated in the comments you can use `table`. The `t()` function puts zip code on the left:

`t(as.matrix(table(data)))`

Comment: I want to convert the matrix to data frame without changing the format. But when I tried `data2 <- as.data.frame(t(as.matrix(table(data)))`, somehow the data structure changed and gave me only three variables: zip, hosp and frequencies. How can I convert the matrix without changing the structure?

Comment: try `as.data.frame.matrix(t(table(df)))`